# Finding a Value in a Cell in Sheet1 and Pasting it to Sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

I want the VBA to find the cell header named "Apple" (in row a1) in Sheet1 and paste that data into cell header named "Orange in Sheet2

```
Sheet1     Sheet2

Apple      Orange
1
2
3
4
```

I am trying to NOT include cell header so it only grabs the number.

Would something like below work?

```
Sheet1.Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Apple", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Selection.EntireColumn row-1.Copy sheet2.range("a2")
```

Something like `entirecolumn row -1` so that it doesn't copy the header cell...
not sure what I am doing but help would be great!

Comment: what have you tried? It is not necessary to copy/paste there are other ways to make the content in the range on sheet2 match what is in the range on sheet1

Comment: `Find()` seems like the way to go.

Comment: Well thanks for the comment, but the two sheets change columns so can't really exactly match two sheets column by column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
Dim rng as range, rngCopy as range, rng2 as range

set rng = Sheet1.Rows(1).Find(What:="Apple", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

if not rng is nothing then

    set rngCopy = Sheet1.range(rng.offset(1,0), _
                               Sheet1.cells(rows.count,rng.column).end(xlUp))

    set rng2 = Sheet2.Rows(1).Find(What:="Orange", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                   LookAt:=xlWhole)

    if not rng2 is nothing then rngCopy.copy rng2.offset(1,0)

end if
```